# Reference javascript file from node package in Azure Web App (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npm, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web Application hosted in Azure.

It's configured to automatically build and deploy from the GitHub repository.

I was using a version of `angular.min.js` which I had installed from a nuget package, and then directly checked in. Now I want to change this, and  incorporate javascript packages from npm instead of nuget.

I did the following:

- Added an npm configuration file
- Add the dependency "angular": "^1.6.5"

Here's the complete `package.json` file:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "name: "asp.net",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
      "angular": "^1.6.5"
   },
   "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Then, in my razor page, I referenced angular directly from the `node_modules` folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This worked on my local machine.
I checked this into Github, and the Azure framework built and deployed my code. However, the folder `node_modules` is not present under `D:\home\site\wwwroot`

I tried added a pre-build step:

```
npm install
```

but this did not solve the problem.

Using kudu, I bought up the debug console on the web server. I set the location to the folder `D:\home\site\wwwroot`, then typed `npm install`. This worked: it created and populated the `node_modules` folder, and my website could now access the angular file.

So, either the build is not restoring the packages, or it is restoring the packages but not deploying them to the `wwwroot` folder.

Is there a correct way to include javascript files from node packages in ASP.NET MVC apps on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

I added a post-deploy step, following the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks).

- In the browser, go to `https://<mywebappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net`
- Activate the Debug Console \ Powershell tab
- Drill to the folder "D:\home\site\deployments\tools"
- Create a folder "PostDeploymentActions"
- In this folder, add a powershell script `post-deploy.ps1`:

The contents of this powershell script:

```
pushd d:\home\site\wwwroot
npm install
popd
```

Now the node packages are installed on the web server with each deployment.

---

At this stage, I'm not sure whether this is the best long-term solution or not....

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice when using GitHub for continuous deployment, we recommend using **Custom Deployment Script** for customizing the deployment process. Please check [this doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) out for details.